# IndexedDb in a Web Worker in the latest Safari?

Tags: safari, undefined, integration, indexeddb, polyfills

I have an existing app which runs on fine in earlier versions of Safari and makes use of an indexedDB polyfill to store data. Most of this activity takes place in a web worker so WebSQL can be accessed from the web worker.

However, I am now trying native indexedDB access using Safari 6.2 and although indexedDB can be referenced in the "main" work thread, when i try to access "self.indexeddb" or "indexeddb" they both come back as undefined.

Has anyone been able to access indexedDB in a web worker in the newest versions of Safari?

Comment: Someone replied to my thread on the Apple Dev forums saying that IndexedDB was not accessible from a web worker, but they did not say anything else. Would be nice if anyone could confirm that they had experienced this in the real world.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing IndexedDB from multiple javascript threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038379/accessing-indexeddb-from-multiple-javascript-threads)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. The referenced question is regarding race conditions. My question was whether it was even possible to access Apple's new implementation of IndexedDB from a web worker - which I have now discovered is NOT possible.

Comment: But doesn't the answer to that question show a solution?

Comment: My question was: "Has anyone been able to access indexedDB in a web worker in the newest versions of Safari?". I also referenced that the version of Safari I was using was version 6.2. This was released on 18th September 2014. The answer to the question you think I am duplicating was posted on 28th January 2012 and makes no reference to Safari.

Comment: How is indexeddb on Safari mobile in 2014 different from indexeddb in 2012? It's a [web standard](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_10.html//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014484-DontLinkElementID_2#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014484-DontLinkElementID_2), so a technique to integrate with a web worker in 2012 should be cross-browser compatible and forward-compatible, unless the [implementation is buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019147/primary-key-issue-on-ios8-implementation-of-indexeddb).

Comment: It's very buggy. which is why I started that thread you linked to. Although IndexedDb is indeed a web standard, being able to access it via a web worker is not. Chrome and Internet Explorer both provide an interface ("self.indexedDb" I believe) to access IDB from a web worker, but Apple do not. I vote to close this now. It doesn't work and it makes me very sad.

Comment: Ack! Any followup or work around? I am sad too.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone been able to access indexedDB in a web worker in the newest versions of Safari?

IndexedDB is accessible from Web Worker since Safari Technology Preview Release 5:

> Safari Technology Preview is a version of Safari for OS X, distributed by Apple, that includes a cutting-edge, in-development version of the WebKit browser engine. It’s a great way to test upcoming WebKit features and give feedback to the people building them when it’s most useful — early in development.

Released on May 15, 2016. The release notes state:

> Enabled IndexedDB in Web Worker scripts
>
> Safari Technology Preview requires a Mac running OS X 10.11.4 or later.
> Release 5 of Safari Technology Preview covers WebKit revisions 200418–201083.

**References**

- [Introducing Safari Technology Preview](https://webkit.org/blog/6017/introducing-safari-technology-preview/)
- [Safari Technology Preview: Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/)
- [Release Notes for Safari Technology Preview 5](https://webkit.org/blog/6415/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-5/)
- [Webkit Bug 149953 – Modern IDB: WebWorker support](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149953)
- [What's New in MacOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/WhatsNewInOSX.html)
- [Primary Key issue on iOS8 implementation of IndexedDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019147/1113772)
- [indexeddb on iOS 8 - Broken Bad](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/9/25/IndexedDB-on-iOS-8--Broken-Bad)

Comment: I was aware that IndexedDB is available now in iOS, the question was moreover can it be accessed from a web worker.

Comment: @jonnyknowsbest Indexed databases in Web Workers are now supported